# How do I convert SQL to XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, namespaces, processing-instruction

I am trying to output SQL as XML to match the exact format as the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProrateImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.aldi-
sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/20151009">
  <Prorates>
    <Prorate>
      <OrderTypeId>1</OrderTypeId>
      <DeliveryDate>2015-10-12T00:00:00+02:00</DeliveryDate>
      <DivNo>632</DivNo>
      <ProrateUnit>1</ProrateUnit>
      <ProrateProducts>
      <ProrateProduct ProductCode="8467">
          <ProrateItems>
            <ProrateItem StoreNo="1">
              <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            </ProrateItem>
            <ProrateItem StoreNo="2">
              <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            </ProrateItem>
            <ProrateItem StoreNo="3">
              <Quantity>5</Quantity>
            </ProrateItem>
          </ProrateItems>
        </ProrateProduct>
      </ProrateProducts>
    </Prorate>
  </Prorates>
</ProrateImport>
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    OrderTypeID,
    DeliveryDate, DivNo,
    ProrateUnit,
    (SELECT  
         ProductOrder [@ProductCode],
         (SELECT 
              ProrateItem [@StoreNo],
              CAST(Quantity AS INT) [Quantity]
          FROM 
              ##Result2 T3
          WHERE
              T3.DivNo = T2.DivNo 
              AND T3.DivNo = T1.DivNo 
              AND T3.DeliveryDate = T2.DeliveryDate 
              AND T3.DeliveryDate = T1.DeliveryDate
              AND T3.ProductOrder = t2.ProductOrder
          FOR XML PATH('ProrateItem'), TYPE, ROOT('ProrateItems')
         )
     FROM 
         ##Result2 T2
     WHERE
         T2.DivNo = T1.DivNo 
         AND T2.DeliveryDate = T1.DeliveryDate
     FOR XML PATH('ProrateProduct'), TYPE, ROOT('ProrateProducts')
    )
FROM 
    ##Result2 T1
GROUP BY 
    OrderTypeID, DeliveryDate, DivNo, ProrateUnit
FOR XML PATH('Prorate'), TYPE, ROOT('Prorates')
```

How do I add in the Following and have the ProrateImport/20151009" change to the current date?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProrateImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.aldi-
sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/20151009">
```

This is my first time I have used XML

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i understand. Did you create the first XML yourself and just need to add the last script?

```
DECLARE @XMLHEADER nvarchar(max)

SET @XMLHEADER = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ProrateImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/'+convert(varchar(8),getdate(),112)+'"
>'

select @xmlheader
```

And then you just need to add the rest of your output from your select statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

- How to introduce namespaces?
- How to introduce namespaces dynamically
- How to add a `<?xml ?>` directive
- two-leveled root (`<ProrateImport><Prorate>`)

### namespaces

You have to use `WITH XMLNAMESSPACES` to introduce a namespace to your query.

Hint: the *naked* `xmlns` is introduced by `DEFAULT`, the `xsi` namespace will be introduced automatically by using `ELEMENTS XSINIL`:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS xsd
                   ,DEFAULT 'http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/20151009')
SELECT 1 AS Dummy 
FOR XML PATH('rowElement'), ELEMENTS XSINIL, ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/20151009" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <rowElement>
    <Dummy>1</Dummy>
  </rowElement>
</root>
```

Note: The namespaces must be stated literally. No computations, no variables!

### dynamic namespaces

This is - out of the box - impossible. But you might use dynamically created SQL and use `EXEC` to get your result. Just create exactly the statement as above

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'' AS xsd
                   ,DEFAULT ''http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)  + ''')
SELECT 1 AS Dummy 
FOR XML PATH(''rowElement''), ELEMENTS XSINIL, ROOT(''root'')';

PRINT @cmd
EXEC(@cmd);
```

the result

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/20171019" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <rowElement>
    <Dummy>1</Dummy>
  </rowElement>
</root>
```

### directive

The directive **cannot be introduced into XML**. SQL-Server will omit any `<?xml ?>` directive! This can only be done on string level:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)=
'
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(''http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'' AS xsd
                   ,DEFAULT ''http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),112)  + ''')
SELECT(
SELECT 1 AS Dummy 
FOR XML PATH(''rowElement''), ELEMENTS XSINIL, ROOT(''root'')) AS MyResult';

CREATE TABLE #resultTable(MyXmlAsString VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO #resultTable(MyXmlAsString)
EXEC(@cmd);

SELECT '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' + MyXmlAsString
FROM #resultTable;
```

The result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns="http://schema.aldi-sued.com/Logistics/Shipping/ProrateImport/20171019" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <rowElement>
        <Dummy>1</Dummy>
    </rowElement>
</root>
```

### two-leveled root

You can nest two `FOR XML` statements to achieve this:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'blah')
SELECT
(
    SELECT 1 AS Dummy
    FOR XML PATH('rowElement'),ROOT('innerRoot'),TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('outerRoot');
```

But the annoying part is, that namespaces are introduced by each sub-select over and over. Not wrong but very annoying! A well known [Microsoft connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements). Please sign in and vote for it! The result:

```
<outerRoot xmlns="blah">
  <innerRoot xmlns="blah">   <!--Here's the second xmlns! -->
    <rowElement>
      <Dummy>1</Dummy>
    </rowElement>
  </innerRoot>
</outerRoot>
```

### Your solution

After explained all this I'd suggest to create the XML without any namespace or declaration (what you are doing already!), then convert the result to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and add the header and the closing footer on string level. This is ugly, but in your case the only way.

Hint: You will not be able to store the final result in a native XML type in SQL Server without loosing the directive.